# order in database table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have sqlite table called notes. It has id, title, text.

In my application user can place notes in the order he wants.
He can drag and move notes changing their positions.

First, i thought to create "position" field. But it's bad idea.
If one note has changed it's position, the other notes also will change their positions. So e.g. if it's gonna be one thousand records, then it's not good idea at all changing all the records because of one action.

How can i solve this thing, so user will change the note position and will save this state to the database?

Comment: keep in mind that you would only 'need' to change the index number for all notes either before or after the one that moved...  sometimes the bad idea is the most straight forward solution.  So if this table is read from much more often than re-ordered, adding an index field is the better choice

Comment: @pnm thanks for suggestion. Is there a way to write one query that will change "position" field for all the records?

Comment: I would recommend maintaining the indexes for each note in your application and updating your table at the appropriate time.

Comment: @pnm the problem is that it's android application and it has a lifecycle that not always depends on me and can be controlled. So I think what i can do, is enable some editting mode allow to drag this notes. then after submit update indexes in database table.

Comment: I think that @pnm is correct on this. If you've got thousands of notes to be moved around, then you're going to have a harder time with the reorder UI than with an update to a thousand rows, databases are fast and an update of a single column to a thousand rows will be fine. I'm not an android developer, but don't you have an event that you could use, onRowReorder or something like that? Then make the database call from that event.

Comment: @NathanKoop of course i  have this event, i will try and tell the results about performance. I will put the counter in millis to check the time for thousand rows. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just store the previous and next node. Then you can always look up the order. Or you just always only save the node.

Comment: Sorting the rows in SQL would require a [CTE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

Answer (score 1):

The database will need another column that contains the user's preferred order.
Adding another column is not a bad idea: add a new column, say ListOrder, that holds an integer datatype.

Display notes in order of increasing ListOrder values.

```
     Select * from Table Order By ListOrder
```

If the user drags a note up by one unit in the UI, then increment the integer in ListOrder for that row by 1.

```
     Update Table Set ListOrder=ListOrder+1 Where ListOrder=(Select ListOrder-1 From Table where Column_x = 'blob')
```

Note that **column_x** is another aspect of the row containing some identifying datatype, such as a username.

Comment: if i understood correctly, this query will change only one record, but what about other records. They will change their positions too.
What does this line do? (Select ListOrder-1 From Table where Column_x = 'blob')

Comment: To move the note by multiple units, set the ListOrder to a specific integer; if the user wants to move the note to the top: `Update Table Set ListOrder=1 Where Column_x = 'blob'`. To answer the second part, that line can be written as `...Where Column_x = 'blob'`. It just specifies the record. I stated in the answer that **column_x** can be the username, but it makes more sense to be something unique to the row, like an id or the text in the note.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that is saving the final positions, at end, when the user will no make more changes. A full scan or something.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: I disagree, how do you know when the user will make no more changes? A big save button at the end of the re-order screen? This would have been appropriate 10 years ago, but that sort of UI is not modern and would feel clunky to an experienced user.

Comment: @NathanKoop i totally agree with you, but what should i do. I don't know sql well, so i can create one query which will change every record appropriately to the formula